# How to configure keyboard shortcuts for special characters on OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, special-characters

How to configure keyboard shortcuts for special character on OS X? For example, one would set ALT+C to ©.

Comment: This question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/49565/73607 on the Apple SA is similar, and has some nice answers.

Answer (score 11):

Create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
    "~c" = (insertText:, "©");
}
```

Applying changes requires reopening applications. The custom keybindings don't work in all applications or views, but they do seem to work in Sublime Text 2.

For more information, see [hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/Cocoa%20Text%20System.html](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/Cocoa%20Text%20System.html) and [osxnotes.net/keybindings.html](http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html).

You could also make a custom keyboard layout with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) or create a `private.xml` in [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en).

Comment: @´ This gives me a syntax error when trying to source the file: `DefaultKeyBinding.dict: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token \`('`

Comment: That link to hcs.harvard.edu... /~jrus ... seems to lead to a malicious site?

Answer (score 5):

To type © on a Mac, it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>

To configure keyboard shortcuts for special characters on OS X:

System Preferences > Language & Text > Text > Symbol & Text substitution.
Use the + on the bottom of the list to add the ones you want.

EDIT 08/19/12:

According to http://www.macworld.com/article/1160500/text_substitutions.html, you can make `Text Substitution` universal in Macs by executing the command in `Terminal`:

```
defaults write -g WebAutomaticTextReplacementEnabled -bool true
```

Comment: I have made an edit to the answer, hope this helps.

Comment: Symbol & Text substitution is not working for my editor, sublime.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sublime, but I found this article which might help in your case: http://www.macworld.com/article/1160500/text_substitutions.html

Comment: @superuser, that link contains some nice info. Please add the `defaults write` and Edit > Substitutions to your answer.

Comment: The defaults command does the same thing as the checkbox in the Language & Text preference pane.

Comment: This answer is no longer timely for Mavericks. Your menu options listed here do not exist now

Comment: In Mavericks, it's Keyboard > Text.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to trick your computer into auto-correcting some string of text to the symbol of your choice.

For example, typing `theta` changes to `θ`

To do this on Mavericks go to: System Preferences > Keyboard > Text