# How to create keyboard shortcuts for the following characters — æ, ø, and å — in macOS? Older answer to another no longer works

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I am using Ubuntu, Arch, Windows, and now also macOS as of recently.

I am a Danish programmer, and I use a U.S. keyboard layout since a lot of characters used for programming are easier to reach than a Danish keyboard layout.

On all systems except for macOS, I have bound the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key with the following keys `'`, `\`, and `]` to produce `æ`, `ø`, and `å`.

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> = æ
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> = ø
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> = å

I would like to configure macOS to do the same, but with a command or preferably the command key to the right of the spacebar.

I found the following [Super User post](https://superuser.com/questions/463456/how-to-configure-keyboard-shortcuts-for-special-characters-on-os-x), but it seems it is for an older version of macOS.

How can achieve the above with the newer macOS?

Comment: You seem to want to create your own keyboard shortcuts, but would the information [presented in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1745275/167207) help? Or how about [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1745267/167207) as well as [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1745265/167207)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those three are already on a Mac keyboard set to English, but they're opt/ `'`, `o` and `a` respectively. You can see this if you open the Keyboard Viewer [top menu bar if you have the language flag showing, or System Prefs>Keyboard. [Prefs & keyboard look different on newer macOS, but the layouts are the same. UK/US is the same for this, too]
If you want to move them, you'll need [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) or manually remap `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`

[image]

Comment: I ended up using Ukulele. Thank you very much